# Pandas DataFrame check if date in array of dates and return True/False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file with dates and `df.head()` looks like this:

```
DateTime
2015-04-21 20:00:00
2015-04-21 20:15:00
2015-04-21 20:30:00
2015-04-21 20:45:00
2015-04-21 21:00:00
```

I am loading this json file using the following code:

```py
json_data = response.read().decode('utf-8', 'replace')

data = json.loads(json_data)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
normalizedTime = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s', origin='unix').dt.floor('15T').dt

df['DateTime'] = normalizedTime.to_pydatetime()
df['Date'] = normalizedTime.date
df['Time'] = normalizedTime.time
```

I also have an array of strings which represent certain dates i want to check agains:

```py
dates = [
    "2016-10-25",
    "2017-01-10",
    "2017-03-28",
    "2017-06-13",
    "2017-08-29",
    "2017-10-24",
    "2018-01-16",
    "2018-07-21", 
    "2018-11-11", 
    "2019-03-12", 
    "2019-06-25", 
    "2019-09-24", 
    "2020-01-14", 
    "2020-07-21"
]
```

So the question is, how can i add the `True/False` result to dataframe if date is in dates array?

```py
df['ImportantDate'] = True/False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert values to strings of dates for same types and test by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['ImportantDate'] = df['Date'].astype(str).isin(dates)
```

If want compare datetimes - remove times (set to `00:00:00`) by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html)     and also convert list to datetimes:

```
df['ImportantDate'] = normalizedTime.floor('d').isin(pd.to_datetime(dates))
```

For compare dates:

```
df['ImportantDate'] = df['Date'].isin(pd.to_datetime(dates).date)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the column to str and then check if `isin`:

```
df['ImportantDate'] = df['Date'].astype(str).isin(dates)
```